# TikZ: clip with Pic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

Title explains it all really, I want to clip a picture using an exiting .pic that I have already defined, as I plan on using this clip shape many times over.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
         clipshape/.pic={\clip (-1,-1) rectangle (1, 1);} %just a rectangle here, but typically a more complex shape.
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \pic {clipshape};
    \fill (0,0) circle (1.1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Obviously the intended end result of this would be a black circle with the sides partially cut off. The MWE does compile but the clip does not occur. Am I going the right way with using pics or do I have to do something more complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two examples : one using `path picture`, the other a standard `clip`.

```
\documentclass[border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
  clipshape 1/.pic={\path[path picture={#1}] (-1,-1) rectangle (1, 1);},
  clipshape 2/.pic={\clip (-1,-1) rectangle (1, 1);#1}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pic at (0,0) {clipshape 1={\fill[green] (0,0) circle (1.1);}};
      \pic at (3,0) {clipshape 2={\fill[red] (0,0) circle (1.1);}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A simple macro definition will do:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*{\clipshape}{
  (-1, -1) rectangle (1, 1)
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
    \clip \clipshape;
    \fill (0,0) circle (1.1);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The macro can then be reused, combined with other path elements and so on.